# How to fix facebook sharer button that appears cutted on wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I want to put a facebook sharer button in my articles. I'm using incubator wordpress theme.
I got the code on fb developers site and it works very well, but it appears cutted (doesn't show how many times the article was shared).

I went to facebook developers page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) , created the code below, and put it in a html type of content, in wordpress. I changed the 75 width in the code, and it didn't work.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2F3ncrypt3d.com%2Fsucesso-sem-hora-marcada%2F&layout=button_count&size=small&width=75&height=20&appId" width="75" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

It was no errors, only appears cutted on the right side. Do you know what can I do for it to totally appear?

Thank you all for your possible help. :)

Comment: For some reason, the code doesnt appear lol
It is here:

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2F3ncrypt3d.com%2Fsucesso-sem-hora-marcada%2F&layout=button_count&size=small&width=75&height=20&appId" width="75" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

Comment: Its quite clear, why this isnt working: the width="75" just cutts off the button, because 
try setting it to 100 or 200 or justget rid of  the width="75" bit completely

Comment: Thanks, @DigitalJedi

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, make `width="100"` of iframe

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button_count&size=small&width=88&height=20&appId" width="100" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```